# xpath expression for regex-like matching?

Tags: ruby, regex, xpath

I want to search div id in an html doc with certain pattern.
I want to match  this pattern in regex:

```
foo_([[:digit:]]{1.8})
```

using xpath. What is the xpath equivalent for the above pattern?

I'm stuck with `//div[@id="foo_` and then what? If someone could continue a legal expression for it.

**EDIT**

Sorry, I think I have to elaborate more. Actually it's not `foo_`, it's `post_message_`

Btw, I use mechanize/nokogiri ( ruby )

Here's the snippet :

```
html_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(myfile))
message_div =  html_doc.xpath('//div[substring(@id,13) = "post_message_" and substring-after(@id, "post_message_") => 0 and substring-after(@id, "post_message_") <= 99999999]')
```

Still failed. Error message:

> Couldn't evaluate expression '`//div[substring(@id,13) = "post_message_" and substring-after(@id, "post_message_") => 0 and substring-after(@id, "post_message_") <= 99999999]`' (Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError)

Comment: It is syntactically invalid to use '=>'. The '>=' operator must be used.

Comment: You probably don't want: substring(@id, 12) = 'post_message_'

but: substring(@id,1,13) = 'post_message_'

or even better: starts-with(@id, 'post_message_')

See my answer.

Comment: I made another change to my answer.

Comment: @DImitre OMG, How could I miss that typo! @_@ Thanks man

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about this (updated):

XPath 1.0:

```
"//div[substring-before(@id, '_') = 'foo' 
       and substring-after(@id, '_') >= 0 
       and substring-after(@id, '_') <= 99999999]"
```

Edit #2: The OP made a change to the question. The following, even more reduced XPath 1.0 expression works for me:

```
"//div[substring(@id, 1, 13) = 'post_message_' 
       and substring(@id, 14) >= 0 
       and substring(@id, 14) <= 99999999]"
```

XPath 2.0 has a convenient [`matches()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches):

```
"//div[matches(@id, '^foo_\d{1,8}$')]"
```

Apart from the better portability, I would expect the numerical expression (XPath 1.0 style) to perform better than the regex test, though this would only become noticeable when processing large data sets.

---

Original version of the answer:

```
"//div[substring-before(@id, '_') = 'foo' 
       and number(substring-after(@id, '_')) = substring-after(@id, '_') 
       and number(substring-after(@id, '_')) &gt;= 0 
       and number(substring-after(@id, '_')) &lt;= 99999999]"
```

The use of the `number()` function is unnecessary, because the mathematical comparison operators coerce their arguments to numbers implicitly, any non-numbers will become `NaN` and the greater than/less than tests will fail.

I also removed the encoding of the angle brackets, since this is an XML requirement, not an XPath requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works now,I use your Xpath 1.0 solution due to better support of Xpath 1.0 in lib-xml. Fyi,Nokogiri has different quotes syntax (see my code above). All in all, Accepted and voted-up :)

Answer (score 6):

As already pointed out, in [**XPath 2.0**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/) it would be good to use its standard regex capabilities with a function like the [**`matches()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) function.

**One possible [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) solution**:

```
//div[starts-with(@id, 'post_message_')
    and
      string-length(@id) = 21
    and
      translate(substring-after(@id, 'post_message_'), 
                '0123456789', 
                ''
                )
     =
      ''
      ]
```

**Do note the following**:

1. The use of the standard XPath function [**`starts-with()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-starts-with).
2. The use of the standard XPath function [**`string-length()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-string-length).
3. The use of the standard XPath function [**`substring-after()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-substring-after).
4. The use of the standard XPath function **[`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#function-translate)**.

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote. ;-) Nice alternative solution, though it does not fulfill the {1,8} conditon the OP asked for. But that is easily fixed with a string-length() test.

Comment: @Tomalak Sorry, I am on a 2-day trip and only have minutes free time to look at SO problems. I'll edit this now.

Answer (score 2):

Or use xpath function matches(string,pattern).

```
  <xsl:if test="matches(name(.),'foo_')">
```

Unfortunately it's not regex, but it might be enough unless you have other foo_ tags you don't need, then I Guess you can add a few more "if" checks to cull them out.

Comment: matches *is* a regexp function, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches: "The function returns true if $input matches the regular expression ..."

Comment: Awesome! I had under estimated matches. But now I need to go back and refactor, my archaic searches !

Answer (score 0):

[Nikkou](https://github.com/tombenner/nikkou) makes this very easy and readable:

```
doc.search('div').attr_matches('id', /post_message_\d{1,8}/)
```