# Extract URL where text matches a regex - with XPath 1.0

Tags: python, regex, xpath, lxml, scrapy

I would like to extract the URL of this type (link text is a number with any number of digits and href is a random text) using an XPath in Scrapy.

- `<a href="http://www.example.com/link_to_some_page.html>3</a>`
- `<a href="http://www.example.com/another_link-abcd.html>45</a>`

I could think of something like

```
HtmlXPathSelector(response).select('//a[matches(text(),"\d+")]/@href')
```

However it appears that XPath 2.0 isn't supported and I can't use regex.

The best single line solution I could search was from this question: [xpath expression for regex-like matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/597944/781695) - Is there a better way in scrapy to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.select('//a[. != "" and translate(., "0123456789", "") = ""]/@href')
```

Comment: +1 smart answer. @Tomalak how about exactly matching a string while ignoring the case in Xpath 1.0 ? E.g. if my string is "Next". I would use something like (r"^next$", re.I). How would I do that without regex?

Comment: @buffer: That's been asked before, several times. Just search for it. ;) - BTW, another variant would be `... and string(number(.)) != 'NaN'`, but that would accept numerical notations beyond "digits only".