# XPath not locating element

Tags: xpath, rspec, capybara

What is wrong with my path to select the following:

```
<label class="form-control-label" for="profile_form_state">State</label>
```

Xpath:

```
xpath = '//label[ends-with(@for, "_state")]'
```

I am using rspec and capybara

```
 expect(rendered).to have_xpath(xpath)
```

Error:

> ```
>    xmlXPathCompOpEval: function ends-with not found
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered by @har07, XPath 1.0 (which browsers implement) doesn’t have an `ends-with` but CSS provides an ends-with attribute selector `$=`

```
expect(rendered).to have_css(‘label[for$=“_state”]’)
```

or you can use regex with Capybaras built-in [`:label` selector](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/Selector)

```
expect(rendered).to have_selector(:label, for: /_state$/)
```

If you really want to stick with XPath over CSS then you can use the xpath gem Capybara uses internally for generating its own XPaths and write

```
xpath = XPath.descendant(:label).where(XPath.attr(:for).ends_with('_start'))
expect(rendered).to have_xpath(xpath)
```

Comment: Would love to just use rspec to locate a css element and it’s previous sibling label and in another case parent form.  What is best way? Otherwise, what is your best recommended approach?

Comment: @user2012677 Without seeing the HTML it's impossible to give the best approach - depends on whether the label is correctly associated with the element, etc.  If the label is correctly associated with the field then if you've already found the field you can just do `find(:label, for: field)` - for a parent form you can do `field.ancestor('form')`

Comment: Are "find() and field.ancestor(), a rspec, xpath or capybara thing? Would I do expect(rendered).find(:label, for:field) and expect(rendered).field.ancestor('form')?

Comment: @user2012677 They're capybara methods not rspec matchers.  This is moving far beyond your original question and it's tough to give a full answer in comments.  Ask a new question with a sample HTML and explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your XPath processor only supports XPath, 1.0 while `ends-with` is defined in XPath 2.0 and above. But you can [simulate `ends-with()` in XPath 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3470779/2998271) using `substring()` and `string-length()` :

```
xpath = '//label["_state" = substring(@for, string-length(@for) - string-length("_state") +1)]'
```

You can shorten the expression a bit by replacing `string-length("_state") +1` with pre-calculated value `5` (length of the word `_state` minus one) :

```
xpath = '//label["_state" = substring(@for, string-length(@for) - 5)]'
```

Comment: Doesn’t caybara run xpath v3?

Comment: I mean [XPath specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/), not ruby xpath library version

Comment: Can I change the specification easily?

Comment: related discussion regarding XPath `matches` which also not supported in version 1.0: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35796197/2998271

Comment: I'm not experienced with ruby, but based on the linked discussion seems like the XPath processor only implement XPath 1.0 so there is no way for you to use XPath 2.0 expression, hence the alternative expression

Answer (score 0):

Other possible Xpath

```
//label[contains(@for, '_state')]
```

or

```
//label[text()='State']
```

or

```
//label[contains(text(), 'State')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following Xpath.

```
xpath = '//label[contains(., "State")]'
```